# Meteor / Apollo: SSL Forcing HTTPS onto Same Port as WSS?

Tags: node.js, meteor, websocket, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to get HTTPS and WSS (for Apollo subscriptions) working in my local dev environment. Even though I have them on two different ports, something seems to be forcing or redirecting the WSS calls to the HTTPS port.

Here's my current code. For SSL access I have installed Meteor package `nourharidy/meteor-ssl`. I can use any comparable package or approach that people have found useful!

As required by `nourharidy/meteor-ssl`, in server/main.js I have:

```
SSL('/path/to/private/server.key','/path/to/private/server.crt', 3100);
```

My ROOT_URL environment variable is:

```
https://10.0.1.10:3100 //I’m using my Mac’s ip address so that another Mac can access it
```

In imports/startup/server/index.js I have:

```
//SET UP APOLLO QUERY / MUTATIONS / PUBSUB
const USING_HTTPS = true;
const httpProtocol =  USING_HTTPS ? "https" : "http"; 
const localHostString = '10.0.1.10' //I’m using my Mac’s ip address so that another Mac can access it

const METEOR_PORT = 3100;
const GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT = 3200;
const subscriptionsEndpoint = `wss://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT}/subscriptions`;

const server = express();
server.use('*', cors({ origin: `${httpProtocol}://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT}` }));
server.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    schema
}));
server.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql',
    subscriptionsEndpoint: subscriptionsEndpoint
}));
// We wrap the express server so that we can attach the WebSocket for subscriptions
const ws = createServer(server);
ws.listen(GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT, () => {
    console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on ${httpProtocol}://${localHostString}:${GRAPHQL_SUBSCRIPTION_PORT}`);

    // Set up the WebSocket for handling GraphQL subscriptions
    new SubscriptionServer({
        execute,
        subscribe,
        schema
    }, {
        server: ws,
        path: '/subscriptions',
    });
});
```

Instead of being at `https://10.0.1.10:3200/graphiql` where it's supposed to be, graphIql is at `https://10.0.1.10:3100/graphiql`! In other words, graphIql loads up just fine on `https://10.0.1.10:3100/graphiql`, but if you go to `https://10.0.1.10:3200/graphiql`, you see `10.0.1.10 unexpectedly closed the connection`.

If I put both HTTPS and WSS on the same port, e.g. 3100, I get an `listen EADDRINUSE :::3100` error.

What's a good server-side setup to get HTTPS and WSS in Meteor/Apollo?

Thanks in advance to all for any info.

Comment: The error says `listen EADDRINUSE :::31001` Is that the real port or a typo? Perhaps it is trying to run mongo on meteor-port+1?

Comment: Did you consider installing `nginx` with `SSL` support on top of Meteor? This way you won't have to play with SSL packages and configure Meteor for SSL at all.

Comment: Yes, @Mikkel, that was a typo. Correcting it...

Comment: @Styx, but will that resolve the issue of getting WSS working? Getting HTTPS working has been easy-- it's getting WSS working at the same time that I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: If someone has this working and could share their server-side setup for it, that would be great. In other words, I don't particularly need to get the error in my code tracked down-- I just want to get this working. :)

Comment: Solved it! It turns out my server setup was fine. Server-side I was building the WSS url like so: `var websocketUri = Meteor.absoluteUrl('subscriptions').replace(/http/, 'ws').replace('3100', '3200');` The Meteor docs for absoluteUrl say: "The server reads from the ROOT_URL environment variable to determine where it is running." In Webstorm I have ROOT_URL set to https://10.0.nn.nn:3100. But for some reason absoluteUrl was returning http://10.0.nn.nn:3000. I.e. it had the wrong port. After correcting the port-- it’s working!

Comment: Updated with more info at SO post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46438035/edit